# Pushwoosh reports Unauthorized

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-messaging, pushwoosh

I have an android app on google play store, when I try to send push notifications on it, all of sent pushes are reported as **"Unauthorized"**, this is happening while I can send push notifications to my test devices successfully.
What could be the problem?

I'm using a `GCM Api key` (which I think it's functional as I can send test pushes successfully) and these are my project dependencies:

```
compile 'com.pushwoosh:pushwoosh:4.10.8'
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:10.2.4"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who encounter this problem, i finally generated a new `GCM Api key` from google developers console and replaced it with the old one in pushwoosh pannel and it solved my problem and my push notifications were sent successfully from that point. As this question is asked a long time ago, currently if you encountered same problem, create new `FCM Api key` and replace it.

Answer (score 0):

The user from the post in [community.pushwoosh.com](https://community.pushwoosh.com/questions/406/not-receiving-push-notification-cordova-34-notification-delivery-report-unauthorized) has the same issue with you. Here is the solution.

> Please note that the "Unauthorized" error in the Control Panel means
>   that Pushwoosh cannot authorize at GCM while sending push
>   notifications. Most probably, something is wrong with the API key.
>
> Please check GCM API key that you entered in your Android settings in
>   the Control Panel. You should try both Browser key and Server key.